# STM32 Gyroscope angle tracking

Tags: embedded, stm32, gyroscope, stm32f4discovery

I'm working with a Gyroscope (L3GD20) with a 2000DPS
[image]

Correct me if their is a mistake,

I start by reading the values High and Low for the 3 axes and concatenate them. Then I multiply every value by `0.07` to convert them into DPS.

My main goal is to track the angle over time, so I simply implemented a Timer which reads the data every `dt = 10 ms`
to integrate `ValueInDPS * 10ms`, here is the code line I'm using :

```
angleX += (resultGyroX)*dt*0.001;   //0.001 to get dt in [seconds]
```

This should give us the value of the angle in [degree] am I right ?
The problem is that the values I'm getting are a little bit weird, for example when I make a rotation of 90°, I get something like 70°...

Comment: You have _described_ a lot of code where it would be far less ambiguous to _show_ the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is a recipe for imprecision and accumulated error.

- You should avoid using floating point (especially if there is no FPU), and especially also if this code is in the timer interrupt handler.
- you should avoid unnecessarily converting to degrees/sec on every sample - that conversion is needed only for presentation, so you should perform it only when you need to need the value - internally the integrator should work in gyro sample units.

Additionally, if you are doing floating point in both an ISR and in a normal thread *and* you have an FPU, you may also encounter unrelated errors, because FPU registers are not preserved and restored in an interrupt handler.  All in all floating point should only be used advisedly.

So let us assume you have a function `gyroIntegrate()` called *precisely* every 10ms:

```
static int32_t ax = 0
static int32_t ay = 0
static int32_t az = 0

void gyroIntegrate( int32_t sample_x, int32_t sample_y, int32_t sample_z)
{
    ax += samplex ;
    ay += sampley ;
    az += samplez ;
}
```

Not `ax` etc. are the integration of the raw sample values and so proportional to the angle relative to the starting position.

To convert `ax` to degrees:

*degrees* = *ax* × *r*<sup>-1</sup> × *s*

Where:

- *r* is the gyro resolution in degrees per second (0.07)
- *s* is the sample rate (100).

Now you would do well to avoid floating point and here it is entirely unnecessary; *r*<sup>-1</sup> x *s* is a constant (1428.571 in this case).  So to read the current angle represented by the integrator, you might have a function:

```
#define GYRO_SIGMA_TO_DEGREESx10 14286

void getAngleXYZ( int32_t* int32_t, int32_t* ydeg, int32_t* zdeg )
{
    *xdeg = (ax * 10) / GYRO_SIGMA_TO_DEGREESx10 ;
    *ydeg = (ax * 10) / GYRO_SIGMA_TO_DEGREESx10 ;
    *zdeg = (ax * 10) / GYRO_SIGMA_TO_DEGREESx10 ;
}
```

`getAngleXYZ()` should be called from the application layer when you need a result - not from the integrator - you do the math at the point of need and have CPU cycles left to do more useful stuff.

Note that in the above I have ignored the possibility of arithmetic overflow of the integrator. As it is it is good for approximately +/-1.5 million degrees +/-4175 rotations), so it may not be a problem in some applications.  You could use an `int64_t` or if you are not interested in the number of rotations, just the absolute angle then, in the integrator:

```
ax += samplex ;
ax %= GYRO_SIGMA_360 ;
```

Where `GYRO_SIGMA_360` equals 514286 (360 x *s* / *r*).

Comment: It is far more complicated :(

Comment: @0___________ integrating a gyro is not complicated. Dealing with zero point, drift, sensor fusion etc is of course more complicated. However this will give better results that the OPs approach.  He has given too little information to determine other sources of error, or whether the "DC bias" has been removed.

Comment: For mems I actually use those STM libraries - they work very well.

Comment: @0___________ agreed, but a much less interesting answer. The techniques and principles discussed here have more general application.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MEMs sensor math is quite complicated.
I would personally use ready libraries provided by the STM https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-mems1.html.

I actually use them, and the results are very good.

Comment: Hello, `@0___________`. looks like you have worked on the MEMs sensor libraries before I really need your help. Basically, I was using ISM330DLC gyro and acc sensor which I have interfaced using example code. So after this process, I was able to get the raw data but the library output is always zero. I got stuck for almost more than 2 months and desperately I need any help. Please let me know if you can help me to solve this.